# replacing text with NA in R

Tags: r, replace, tidyverse

I have a variable `PC_R` in dataframe `jd_df` that describes laboratory test results. I'd like to replace some of the data in this variable (e.g. tf, QNS, rej) with NA. I've tried this code:

```
 jd_df %>%
  replace(PC_R,TF,NA)
```

and this:

```
jd_df %>%
  replace(jd_df,PC_R==TF,NA)
```

and this:

```
jd_df %>%
  replace(PC_R,"TF","NA")
```

and this:

```
jd_df %>%
  replace(jd_df,PC_R%in%TF,NA)
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Error in replace(., jd_df, PC_R %in% TF, NA) : unused argument (NA)
```

I'm wondering if the replace command is not the way to go.

Comment: You could try `jd_df %>% mutate(PC_R = replace(PC_R, PC_R %in% TF, NA))`

Comment: @akrun Thanks! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using case_when as demonstrated using the iris dataset below

```r
library(dplyr)
iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) %>% 
  mutate(Species = case_when(
    Species == "setosa" ~ NA_character_, 
    TRUE ~ Species
  ))
```

Multiple changes can be specified as such:

```r
iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) %>% 
  mutate(Species = case_when(
    Species == "setosa" | Species == "versicolor" ~ NA_character_, 
    TRUE ~ Species
  ))
```

Created on 2019-02-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: That works. Can I apply this code for multiple words or would it have to be one line at a time? I tried 
     mutate(PC_R = case_when(PC_R == "TF",PC_R =="tf" ~ NA_character_, TRUE ~ PC_R))
 but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

The `case_when()` answer above works well! A simpler alternative is the `na_if()` function, which replaces a specified string with `NA`. As such:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  mutate(Species = na_if(Species, "setosa"))
```

This will change all instances of `setosa` to `NA` in the column `Species`. In your case, it could be:

```
jd_df %>%
  mutate(PC_R = na_if(PC_R, "TF"))
```

Which replaces all `"TF"` with `NA`. You can repeat the code as needed to catch all your intended `NA` values:

```
jd_df %>%
  mutate(PC_R = na_if(PC_R, "TF"),
         PC_R = na_if(PC_R, "QNS"),
         PC_R = na_if(PC_R, "rej"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this works to change multiple character text to NA:

```
jd_df %>% mutate(PC_R = replace(PC_R, PC_R %in% "TF"|PC_R %in% "tf"|PC_R %in% "rej",NA))
```